# Defining a function on an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
def featureScaling(arr):

     arr= [x1,x2,x3]
     y=(x2-x1)/(x3-x1)
     return y

data = [115, 140, 175]
print (featureScaling(data))
```

I want to define a function on an array that divides the difference of the of the first two terms by the difference of the third and first term but I keep getting an error saying that x1 is not defined. I am new to coding and could really use the help.

Comment: Because you would have to define `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. You could unpack `arr` into the variables: `x1, x2, x3 = arr` but this will fail if you don't always have exactly 3 values.

Comment: how about `x1, x2, x3 = arr[0:3]` ?

Comment: `arr= [x1,x2,x3]` should be `x1, x2, x3 = arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]`

Comment: @roganjosh It should be noted that "failing" might be what is best for the situation. If the function is only meant to take a list of length 3, then throwing the resulting error might be what's actually appropriate. I only point it out because sometimes new programmers are afraid of exceptions and think they should be avoided at all cost, even when it throwing one is what should actually happen.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal mm, I would prefer just directly unpacking. Your approach is more robust in the case that the input is _longer_ but still open to failing if the list is shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input variable is defined in the scope of your function as `arr`, but then you proceed to redefine `arr` to `arr=[x1,x2,x3]`, but`x1`, `x2` and `x3` are not defined. Instead, you can use indexing and redefine your function like so:

```
def featureScaling(arr):

     return (arr[1] - arr[0]) / (arr[2] - arr[0])

data = [115, 140, 175]

print(featureScaling(data))
```

This returns:

```
0.4166666666666667
```

Answer (score 2):

arr is an argument in your function, so there's no need to define it in the body of the function. The line `arr= [x1,x2,x3]` tries to redefine the array that you passed in, which is why x1, x2, and x3 aren't defined. You need to define these 3 items in terms of the array, not the other way around.

Comment: You've correctly identified what's wrong, but it might be helpful to indicate what OP should replace it with. `x1,x2,x3 = arr` is what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work.

 With zero based indexing for a list in Python, you can refer to the elements of a list x by x[0] for the first element, x[1] for the second element and so on.

 Since the values of x1 x2 x3 in your code does not have a value, it is not defined and generates an error.

```
def featureScaling(arr):

     y=(arr[1]-arr[0])/(arr[2]-arr[0])
     return y

data = [115, 140, 175]
print (featureScaling(data))
```

Comment: This would indeed "work" but it would be helpful if you could explain why this would work.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the List Index Concept instead of X1,X2 and X3

```
 def featureScaling(arr):
        y=(arr[1]-arr[0])/(arr[2]-arr[0])
        return y

 data = [115, 140, 175]
 print (featureScaling(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to a function this array `->` is pointing to some memory location , In you code. you are trying assign you array to point to a different memory location,its fine to do it but the values used must be defined before . Now what i have done is i have just remove that statement and just used the elements , we can address array elements by the index values , arr[0] refers to the first value in array

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
def featureScaling(arr):
     y=(arr[1]-arr[0])/(arr[2]-arr[0])
     return y

data = [115, 140, 175]
print (featureScaling(data))
```

This version runs of python3 and python2 with floating point precision

**Output**

```
0.416666666667
```

Comment: This is a very confusing discussion on names and scope.

Comment: i dont get it whats confusing ?

Comment: "In you code. you are trying ssigned you array to assign to memory location its fine to do it but the values used must be defined before ." What are you trying to say there?

Comment: `arr= [x1,x2,x3]` This statement in which x1 x2 x3 are not defined before and your are assigning to a new variable